# How to deploy a Camunda process while building a Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, camunda

Currently I am developing a software which uses Camunda and interacts with a certain Camunda process.

All of this is intended to be delivered as a single 'package'. To do this, I plan on simply using a Camunda Docker container and another container which runs my software. To put it all together I intend to use docker-compose.

For the Camunda container I currently use the 'official' image which you can find here: https://hub.docker.com/r/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/
I know that it is not for production use yet, but currently it works fine.

To clean it up a little, I derive from the official image and delete certain files and folders. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:7.11.0

RUN rm -r /camunda/webapps/camunda-invoice
RUN rm -r /camunda/webapps/examples
```

The problem I am encountering right now is that, as far as I know, you have to use the REST Api of Camunda to deploy a process. I did not find any information on deploying it by putting it in a certain directory or something.

For my use case it would be perfect if the Camunda process was deployed while *building the Docker image*. But I cannot think of a solution of how to do that.

Theoretically, I have to start the Camunda engine during building, deploy the process and stop it afterwards. Did anyone try that already with the official Camunda docker image? Or do you have a better solution for my problem?

An alternative would be to deploy the process via the software I am developing. But I think that is a rather ugly solution and I would like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance,
Timo

Comment: is it an option to do it with curl commands using the REST API? That is to run curl commands in the Dockerfile during build. I can give you a camunda image with curl already install and there are tutorials how to deploy and start a process using curl commands.

Comment: Yeah I tried that already and also had it working with curl. The problem is, that you need Camunda to be running if you want to deploy a process via REST api. I was able to deploy the Camunda process as soon as I started a container and made the curl call via `docker exec`. But I could not get it working during the build of the docker image.

Comment: We work with Docker -  but we deploy our standard processes on startup in our application

Comment: @pme Thank you, this is the solution we went for now as well. Maybe this even has some advantages concerning update mechanisms / migrations for future updates and so on.